# zip command on Centos not preserving french special characters

Tags: linux, encoding, localization, centos, zip

I have a vagrant machine, running Centos, that is more or less identical to the prod environment I am working on.
I just encountered a  difference in the way the files are packed using zip command on vagrant comparing with the same command on the same folder on the production environment.
The folder to be packed with `zip -r archive.zip "Target Folder"` command contains some PDF files which names contain french special characters such as é or à.
Running the command from prod, works just fine, but on my VM all those unknown characters are converted to T letter inside the archive, also in the unpacked folder.
Any suggestions what settings should I check in order to change this behaviour?

Comment: what is set of LANG variable?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the `zip` & `unzip` programs. There are a couple of possible scenarios

1. The filenames in the zip archive are not preserving the french special characters at all.
2. The filenames are being stored correctly, but the unzip program doesn't know how to deal with french special characters.

First thing to check is that the build of `zip` on both machines supports Unicode. If you don't see the the `UNICODE_SUPPORT` line, that is a problem.

```
$ zip -v
...
Zip special compilation options:
    USE_EF_UT_TIME       (store Universal Time)
    SYMLINK_SUPPORT      (symbolic links supported)
    LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT   (can read and write large files on file system)
    ZIP64_SUPPORT        (use Zip64 to store large files in archives)
    UNICODE_SUPPORT      (store and read UTF-8 Unicode paths)
    STORE_UNIX_UIDs_GIDs (store UID/GID sizes/values using new extra field)
    UIDGID_NOT_16BIT     (old Unix 16-bit UID/GID extra field not used)
    [encryption, version 2.91 of 05 Jan 2007] (modified for Zip 3)
```

Now run the same command with `unzip`. Again, if you don't see the `UNICODE_SUPPORT` line, that is a problem.

If the `zip` & `unzuip` programs on both boxes fully support Unicode, the issue is likely to be the locale setting on the boxes. Start by running the `locale` command. You need to see UTF-8

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

If this is where the issue is at, I'd expect the box that does support french characters to have UTF-8 in the `LC_`  variables and your other box to not have UTF-8.